# Show Content at the top of the browser window

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I need to show this grid always at header position of form when I do add, delete, update operations. Any body please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
      <asp:GridView ID="Grd_View" ShowFooter="True" runat="server" OnRowEditing="Grd_View_RowEditing" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataKeyNames="CustomerCode" CellPadding="4" OnRowCommand="Grd_View_RowCommand" GridLines="None"
    AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" CssClass="style2" ForeColor="#333333" Width="569px" OnRowDataBound="Grd_View_RowDataBound" OnRowDeleting="Grd_View_RowDeleting">
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#555555" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerCode" HeaderText="CustomerCode" InsertVisible="False"
            ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CustomerCode" />

        <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerName" HeaderText="CustomerName" SortExpression="CustomerName" />

        <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" SortExpression="Address" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TellNo" HeaderText="TellNo" SortExpression="TellNo" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FaxNo" HeaderText="FaxNo" SortExpression="FaxNo" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnEdit" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("CustomerCode")%>' CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit">
                </asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("CustomerCode")%>' CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete">
                </asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnNew" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("CustomerCode")%>' CommandName="New" Text="New">
                </asp:LinkButton>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>

    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#777777" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#555555" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />

</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: have a look at my answer. hope it will help you to solve your problem. Don't forget to upvote and mark it as an answer so that it may help other developers as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your grid view inside div tag with **top**, **left** and **position** style as mentioned below :

```
<div style="top: 0%; left: 45%; position: absolute; z-index: 999">
    <asp:GridView ID="Grd_View" ShowFooter="True" runat="server" OnRowEditing="Grd_View_RowEditing" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        DataKeyNames="CustomerCode" CellPadding="4" OnRowCommand="Grd_View_RowCommand" GridLines="None"
        AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" CssClass="style2" ForeColor="#333333" Width="569px" OnRowDataBound="Grd_View_RowDataBound" OnRowDeleting="Grd_View_RowDeleting">
        ...
        ...
        ...
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to Wrap Your Grid view inside Fixed Div for Fixed Header
For ex:

```
<div style ="height:200px; width:617px; overflow:auto;">
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
    AutoGenerateColumns = "false" Font-Names = "Arial" ShowHeader = "false"
    Font-Size = "11pt" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor = "#C2D69B" >
   <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width = "150px" DataField = "CustomerID" />
    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width = "150px" DataField = "City" />
    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width = "150px" DataField = "Country" />
    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width = "150px" DataField = "PostalCode" />
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
</div>
```

Comment: i mean when i open the form Grid view should appear at top and middle position sir...